# Find the type of the elements from the type of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, metaprogramming

Suppose I have a type `T` which is guaranteed to be an array (eg. `int[32]`). How do I get the type of the elements from the type of the array?

I found a way to do it, but it involves declaring a dummy temporary variable, which I would like to avoid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
string getArrayType() {
    // Is there a better way to do this?
    T dummy;
    return typeid(dummy[0]).name();
}

int main() {
    cout << getArrayType<int[1]>() << endl;     // i
    cout << getArrayType<float[1]>() << endl;   // f
}
```

Comment: `typeid(std::declval<T>()[0])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`std::remove_all_extents`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_all_extents) as well

```
return typeid(typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type).name();
```

The documentation for this states

> If `T` is a multidimensional array of some type `X`, provides the member typedef `type` equal to `X`, otherwise type is `T`.

So it will remove the array type to get at the underlying type contained within that array

Answer (score 2):

```
std::remove_all_extents<T>::type
```

found in the `<type_traits>` header. And, if your standard library is C++14 rdy

```
std::remove_all_extents_t<T>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to create a unnecessary variable you can use [`std::remove_extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_extent).  It will give you the element type of the array type.  That would look like

```
template <typename T>
string getArrayType() {
    return typeid(typename std::remove_extent<T>::type).name();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I have a type T which is guaranteed to be an array (eg. int[32]). How do I get the type of the elements from the type of the array?

If you use `typeid().name()`, as in you example, you get the **name** of the type, not the type.

If you want the type, and use it compile time, and you want it to declare variables, you can define a type traits as follows

```
template <typename>  
struct typeOfArray
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t N> 
struct typeOfArray<T[N]>
 { using type = T; };
```

The following is a full (but c++11) working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>  
struct typeOfArray
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t N> 
struct typeOfArray<T[N]>
 { using type = T; };

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same<int,
                 typename typeOfArray<int[1]>::type>::value, "!" );

   static_assert( std::is_same<float,
                 typename typeOfArray<float[1]>::type>::value, "!" );

   typename typeOfArray<int[1]>::type i { 42 };

   std::cout << i << std::endl;
 }
```

If you have to work with c++98, you can't use `using`, so instead of

```
using type = T;
```

you have to use `typedef`

```
typedef T type;
```

The following is a c++98 example (using `typeid().name()` also)

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template <typename>  
struct typeOfArray
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t N> 
struct typeOfArray<T[N]>
 { typedef T type; };

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << typeid(typeOfArray<int[1]>::type).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(typeOfArray<float[1]>::type).name() << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: "If you use typeid().name() [..] you get the name of the type" - Yeah, I know : )
I just used that as a way to test that I was getting the type I wanted, since I didn't know how to "return" a type.

Comment: @SlySherZ - I think you should explain this in your question; as you can see, you're getting answers tailored to get the name of the type where getting the type with a type traits is very simple.